# Powershell No Logon Servers Available

Tags: script, powershell, windows-domain

I have one deployment server A, my local machine B and the server I'm accessing C. When I'm running a test script from B -> C it's successful. When I'm running that same script from A -> C it fails, I can ping it but not run anything else.

Test Script:

```
$credential2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(("Test\ci"), (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force))
Test-Connection -ComputerName C

invoke-command -computername C { get-UICulture } -Credential $credential2
```

The error message:

```
[C] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
 following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service
 the logon request.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or us
e HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information,
 see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Final notes:
- A, B are on the same domain, C is a workgroup
- Enable-PSRemoting (done)
- Modify group policy (done)
- Set-ExecutionPolicy (done)
- Firewall open (done)

I'm running out of ideas, any guesses or stuff I should follow up on? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284132/winrm-cannot-process-the-request-fails-only-over-a-specific-domain

Comment: I finally figured it out. My Group Policy was set to allow servers on the same domain. I needed to set this to allow all * or disable it. I think I got carried away when that was configured.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the important part was the verify my policy settings. Server C (workgroup) was setup to allow servers like A, B on the domain to connect. At some point I set server A with the same settings. Since C is on a workgroup, A didn't trust it.

The fix was to remove/update the settings from A to accommodate this scenario.